# For what values of $b$ is the expression $x^2-3x+b$ factorable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

This is from a summer work packet for high school AP Calculus. I've never seen anything like this. I played around with it and got this as a best guess:
$$\{ b \in \Bbb{Q} \; | \; b \le 2.25 \}$$
I'm not sure if that's formatted the right way but whatever. Sorry in advanced if I am breaking any rules for asking questions (I just skimmed through the "How to Ask" page).

(My bad about copying the wrong problem)

Comment: If a quadatic is not factorisable it means it has no real roots....

Comment: It depends what "factorable" means in this context.  From the context, I'm guessing that the working definition is that a polynomial is factorable iff it has rational roots.

Comment: A good idea here is to look at the discriminant $b^2 - 48$.

Comment: What do you mean by "factorable"? Factorable over $\Bbb Z$, over $\Bbb Q$, over $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the expression to be factorable (over the real numbers), the quadratic equation
$$
x^2 - 3x + b = 0
$$
has to have two real (not necessarily distinct) roots.  This condition is equivalent to the discriminant being nonnegative:
$$
3^2 - 4b \geq 0.
$$

Comment: Does this mean I'm right? Thanks for the stuff about discriminates thats helpful (also @Omnomnomnom cuz i cant upvote comments yet)

Answer (score 1):

$x^2  - 3x + b = (x-r_1)(x-r_2) = x^2 - (r_1 + r_2)x + r_1r_2$ implies that $3 = r_1+r_2$ and $b = r_1r_2$

Comment: I'm confused sorry

Comment: @Cahion3 It means you can pick whatever value you want for $r_1$ and from there you automatically get $r_2$ and $b$. There are infinitely many solutions, unless there is extra wording in your problem putting any restrictions on anything.